# Resize menu into layer

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have this JavaFX menu which is not working properly:

```
public class CreatingMenus {

    // Generate Menu
    public void initMenu(Stage primaryStage, Group root, Scene scene) {

        // Call Menu Actions from Java Method MenuActions
        final MenuActions ma = new MenuActions();

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        // File menu - new, save, close, exit
        Menu menu = new Menu("File");
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("New"));
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Save"));
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Close"));
        menu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());

        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

        // Exit from the application
        menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                // This Java Method is called from the Java Class MenuActions
                ma.programExit(); // Exit program
            }
        });

        menu.getItems().add(menuItem);

        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

        // Options menu - Preferences
        Menu options = new Menu("Options");
        options.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Preferences"));

        menuBar.getMenus().add(options);

        // Help menu - About
        Menu help = new Menu("Help");

        MenuItem helpItem = new MenuItem("About");

        // Exit from the application
        helpItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                aboutDialog();
            }
        });

        help.getItems().add(helpItem);

        menuBar.getMenus().add(help);

        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());

        menuBar.setLayoutX(0);
        menuBar.setLayoutY(0);

        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);

    }

    public void aboutDialog() {

        final int xSize = 640;
        final int ySize = 480;
        final String logoImage = "/logo.png";
        final Color backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
        final String text = "SQL Browser";
        final String version = "Product Version: 1.0";
        final String license = "License Information";

        final Stage aboutDialog = new Stage();
        aboutDialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

        // Logo
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(logoImage));
        ImageView logo = new ImageView(image);

        grid.add(logo, 1, 0);

        // Product name
        Text productName = new Text(text);
        productName.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        grid.add(productName, 0, 2);

        // Product version
        Text productVersion = new Text(version);
        productVersion.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        grid.add(productVersion, 0, 3);

        // Product License
        Text productLicense = new Text(license);
        productLicense.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        grid.add(productLicense, 0, 4);

        // Close Button
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");

        closeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Close the dialog when "Close" button is pressed
                aboutDialog.close();
            }
        });
        grid.add(closeButton, 5, 18);

        // Configure dialog size and background color
        Scene aboutDialogScene = new Scene(grid, xSize, ySize, backgroundColor);
        aboutDialog.setScene(aboutDialogScene);
        aboutDialog.show();

    }
}
```

When I add this menu it overrides the other components into the application and they are not responsible because I suppose they are behind this layer. Can you tell how I can isolate this menu in separate layer because I don't want to place other components behind.

***EDIT***

When I use the menu code I get this result:

[image]

When I remove the the menu code I get this result and the application is working properly:

[image]

The problem somewhere into the menu code.

Comment: Please add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Maybe you have added the menu to the wrong parent. Your code doesn't show to which `Group` you are adding it and what happens before and after.

Comment: I pasted here the complete source code: http://pastebin.com/4LiffWtt

Comment: that is not the same question, in this question the menu doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

*Scene Width Binding*

Stage width contains window borders and a title bar - which are irrelevant to internal layout.

To fill the scene width with something using binding, bind the preferred size of the thing to a scene size and not the stage size:

```
menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(menuBar.getScene().widthProperty());
```

Or (usually preferred) you can use alternate layout panes and layout constraints which perform the sizing automatically.  For your particular layout a [BorderPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) might be useful.

You may have additional issues with your implementation which cause problems (I have not checked).

*Using Groups for Layout*

Your pastebin code uses a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) for the main scene layout root.  Group is generally a poor choice for laying out a flexibly sized screen like your example.  A group is not re-sizable.  Instead it is advisable to use a re-sizable [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) as referred to above.

*Tool Support*

1. [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) is invaluable in debugging existing layout issues.
2. [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) is great for rapid prototyping of various layouts.

I strongly advise using these tools to help understand how layouts work and to provide you with the tools and knowledge you need to debug layout issues yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me without any changes. You might should check your Java/JavaFx versions. I am using 1.7_17, 64 bits on windows.
[image]

I have added some images (I don't have yours) to get sure the behaviour you get is not because of them.

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, sorry. You could also run your project from the command line with any other java installation.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with javafx on centos, yes. To get behind this try running one of the [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/menu_controls.htm). Your code works on my machine on windows 7.

Comment: I found what causes the problem! I remove this line: `menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());` And the menu is not auto sized.

Comment: @PeterPenzov great! It sounds as a javafx bug to me.

Comment: Is there other way to get main stage width property as system value and use it to size the menu width?